# How to return auto increment value after inserted?

Tags: postgresql

`INSERT ON CONFLICT` will still increase auto increment. To avoid that, I use command below, but how to get `pid` after inserted?

```
WITH s AS (
    SELECT pid FROM area WHERE area_name = 'testarea'
), i AS (
    INSERT INTO area (area_name, active, users_pid)
    SELECT 'testarea', true, 0 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM s)
    RETURNING pid
)
UPDATE area 
SET active = true
WHERE pid = (SELECT pid FROM s)
RETURNING pid
```

`pid` is not returning for `INSERT`. I expect both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` to return `pid`.

Comment: Well your `INSERT` has no `returning` clause. How do you expect it to return the generated ID?

Comment: I used Returning pid after INSERT but it still returns empty

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSql has the advantage of using Sequences for auto increment values. So instead of letting the database engine handle the value, you can select the next one from the sequence.

```
SELECT nextval('sequence');
```

By doing that you are in control of the value. You can do whatever you want with it. In your case return it to the caller.

Here is a link to [sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-sequence.html)

Comment: `nextval()` generates a number one GREATER than the last request so at best you will get a number that is one out. You could run this before each insert (inserting the generated number into pid) but you would still be incrementing the count for each update.

Comment: What i am trying so say, is that his approach is wrong. He must reorganize the queries probably.

Comment: if I use netval('sequence') then it returns current pid+1, I expect the most recent pid that already inserted or updated , of course if it updated then current pid is the pid of the record that being updated .. please help

Comment: Select next PID before using it in the query, execute the query and return PID